# mysql select highest record for each relation

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following data:

```
=========================================
| name        |  version   | project_id |
=========================================
| foo         |           1|           1|
| new foo     |           2|           1|
| bar         |           1|           2|
=========================================
```

How can I write a query that returns the highest version record for each product? from the table above, I'd want the following results:

```
=========================================
| name        |  version   | project_id |
=========================================
| new foo     |           2|           1|
| bar         |           1|           2|
=========================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t1.name, t1.version, t1.project_id
FROM
  tablename t1
JOIN
  (SELECT max(version) as version, project_id FROM tablename GROUP BY project_id) t2
ON t1.project_id = t2.project_id AND t1.version = t2.version
```

Answer (score 4):

test table

[image]

the query

[image]

the result

[image]

be win my friend :)

Comment: why does it return 'foo' instead of 'new foo' ? that's the result I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

A very simplest way of doing this is shown below

```
select substring_index(group_concat(`name` order by version),',',-1) as `name`,
max(version) as version,project_id 
from your_table 
group by project_id 
order by projec`t_id;
```